# Separate values in cell into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells that contain values separated by commas. Some of these cells start with either an apostrophe, or a comma, while others start with numbers. I have tried to use `arrNew = range("A1").value` (where cell A1 contains the data to be put into the array) but this only returns a variable containing the entire string.

Is there any way to put split the data, using VBA, so that each value in the cell is correctly in the array as a separate element?

Comment: `Split` might be helpful.

Comment: Do you have actual sample data and expected returns? Also, is VBA a must?

Comment: @JvdV VBA is a must as there will be thousands of rows of data, and hundreds of values in the cell. Also VBA as no other languages (python, etc. available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Public Function parsee(s As String)
    Dim arr, temp, i As Long
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    ReDim temp(1 To 1, LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        temp(1, i) = arr(i)
    Next i

    parsee = temp
End Function
```

[image]

Just select the block of cells adjacent to **A1** and array-enter the formula.

Because I am using Excel 365, the formula does not need to be array-entered; it just spills horizontally.